# Does os.getuid() == 0 mean the root user?

Tags: python, python-os

In some of the code, I have conditions on os.getuid() == 0. Does this mean the script is checking if the user is root and needs "sudo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, yes. On systems where this makes sense at all, [UID 0 implies the user is root](https://superuser.com/a/626845/2269), and that is what the code is checking.